# Getting the list of uncorrelated indices

Tags: python, list, sorting, correlation

I am hung up in a typical logical problem which I mention here. I have a list of arrays with say 100 vectors 'V' and each vector of 21 values like this

```
v1 = [1.2,3.4,5,1,23,...,2.9]   #length is 21
v2 = [0,3.4,12,11,32,...,1.3]   #length is 21
...            ...                  ...
...            ...                  ...
v100 = [1,2,32,4,7.8,...,1.2]   #length is 21
```

Now I need to calculate correlation values of each vector v(i) with all other vectors v(j) ( where

```
corr(v(i) == v(j)) = 1 always # because correlation between same vectors
```

like this I calculated the correlation values for each vector thus I have a list of correlation values with dimensions 100 x 100 and say the name of list is 'c_val'

I created a filter like this

```
for i in range(len(v)):
    for j in range(len(v[i])): 
        if v[i][j] >= 0.8 and i!=j: high_corr_val.append([i,j])
```

Thus this gives me pair of indices for which the correlation value is equal to or greater than 0.8. The list is like this

```
[1,14],[1,23],[1,33],[2,0],[2,12],[2,23] ....... [23,1],[23,3],[23,33] .....
```

My task is to, take out and keep only those indices which are unique and create a final list where the correlation value among any two indices is not more than 0.8 (or whatever value i set)

I tried but the problem that make it difficult for me is that if I keep 1 and delete 23 then I must delete 2 and 23 from the first list. This avoids me from running the loop in any way.

Please help me out with a solution. If more description is needed please let me know.

Also please tell me know what is the best possible way to create a list of vectors correlated among them highly in this way

```
[1,14,23,33]
[0,2,12]
...
...
```

thanks in advance ... I am providing a link to the file of vectors v1 to v100

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4uppagwv2vzx9qg/file_temp_val.txt

Comment: Are you assuming that indices [1,2] and [2,1] are equal?

Comment: yes they are obviously. I kept them to ensure that the list indices and indices in actual do not mismatch

Comment: and you want to remove one of them?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a collection of all the unique indices you want to keep, rather than a list of pairs with overlaps. You can use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) and [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to get this:

```
from itertools import chain

indices = set(chain.from_iterable(high_corr_val))
```

Then you can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) in a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to process the list of vectors:

```
high_corr_vect = [v for i, v in enumerate(vectors) if i in indices]
```